# Mongoid order by length of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sorting, mongoid

> How to sort the Mongoid model by the length of the array which is a field    inside the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document says that you can't orderby using size.

Try adding a new column containing the value of size and sort it which will work as order by.

Answer (score 2):

Mongo documentation [says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/):

> You cannot use $size to find a range of sizes (for example: arrays
>   with more than 1 element). If you need to query for a range, create an
>   extra size field that you increment when you add elements. Indexes
>   cannot be used for the $size portion of a query, although if other
>   query expressions are included indexes may be used to search for
>   matches on that portion of the query expression.

So we cannot order by using mongo's `$size`.

You can solve your task by adding new field, which will store array size.

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :likes, type: Array, default: []
  field :likes_size, type: Integer

  before_save do
    self.likes_size = likes.size
  end
end
```

Sort `posts` by `likes_size`:

```
Post.order_by(likes_size: :desc)
```

Comment: I want to sort the collection based on field which is inside the model and its an array. For eg Post is the model and "likes" is the field which is an array of user_id. So I want to sort Post based on the length of the likes array.

Comment: Thanks, one more quick question I have Postactivity which is a model which  has post_id as the foreign key (has_one relation) and this model has the likes array. now how do I sort the Post model. Thanks in advance ...really appreciate your time.

Comment: @BalajiThiru can you please create new question with all details. I will try to help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372455/mongoid-sort-model-based-on-array-size-which-is-in-other-model-has-one-relatio

Answer (score -1):

In ruby, you can sort an array like this :

```
my_array.sort_by(&:my_attr)
```

It will sort the array `my_array` by the attribute `my_attr` of each element inside the array.

You can also write it like this :

```
my_array.sort_by{|element| element.my_attr }
```

Which is exactly the same, it will sort by the `my_attr` attribute of each element. This second syntax is for when you want a more complex sort condition than just the result of a method of each element.

Documentation : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by

Comment: How does this apply to the question? The OP has an array field inside MongoDB and they want to sort the MongoDB collection by the length of that array.

Comment: I want to sort the collection based on field which is inside the model and its an array. For eg Post is the model and "likes" is the field which is an array of user_id. So I want to sort Post based on the length of the likes array. @muistooshort thats exactly what I want.