# Mongoid sort Model based on array size which is in other Model (has_one) relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have `Postactivity` model, which has `post_id` as the foreign key of the Post Model (has_one relation) and this `Postactivity` model has the likes array.

How i can sort `Post` model by `likes`?

```
class Post
  has_one :postactivity, foreign_key: :post_activity_id, class_name:"PostActivity"
end

class PostActivity
  field :likes, type: Array  
  belongs_to :post, foreign_key: :post_id, class_name: "Post"
end
```

Comment: Can you provide this models?

Comment: I have added the models

Comment: There are no JOINs in MongoDB so you can only work with one collection at a time. Either do the JOIN manually in Ruby or denormalize (i.e. copy data around and keep things synchronized as the array changes). MongoDB doesn't lend itself to factored data models, everything ends up everywhere in multiple copies that are hopefully consistent.

Comment: How do I join manually, can you please give an example, I cannot denormalize Thats a lot of change in my code.

Comment: @farhatmihalko can u pls help me with this issue.

Comment: @BalajiThiru is your models use `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: @farhatmihalko no its Mongoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PostActivity
  field :likes, type: Array
  field :likes_count, type: Integer, default: 0 
  belongs_to :post, foreign_key: :post_id, class_name: "Post"

  before_save do
    self.likes_count = lies.size
  end
end
```

Now you can sort PostActivity model by `likes_count` field.

```
PostActivity.order_by(:likes_count => :desc)
```

You will have sorted `PostActivity` instances. If you will need post, you can get them by call:

```
PostActivity.order_by(:likes_count => :desc).first.post
```

Comment: Its giving me just the first post. I want all the post sorted in the instance variable

Comment: I have posted an answer is there any other efficient way. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`posts =Array.new

    PostActivity.order_by(:likes_count => :desc).each do |pa|

    posts << pa.post

    end`  **this worked for me**