# Optimizing queries which priortize non-empty text fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm working on a very large, long-running Rails monolith which is using Mongoid.  I've been asked to find and optimize slow running queries, which I've started doing with the help of the mLab plugin in Heroku.

This query (some column names redacted) comes up as the number one slowest running function:

```
{
  "status":"<val>",
  "from":{"$regex":"<val>","$options":"<val>"},
  "text":{"$regex":"<val>","$options":"<val>"},
  "field_x":{"$gte":"<val>"},
  "field_y":{"$gte":"<val>"},
  "field_z":{"$gte":"<val>"}
}
```

mLab gives some recommendations to improve slow running queries and I've added the index it suggested, but I wonder if I can make the Rails query itself better.  It looks like this (model names changed):

```
@reviews = object.reviews.active.and(:text.ne => nil, :text.ne => '').desc(:created_at)
@reviews += object.reviews.active.any_of({text: nil}, {text: ''}).desc(:created_at)
```

I did not write this code, but as I understand it, it wants to prioritize reviews with text so that a 5-star review with text `OMG, LIKE TOTALLY AMAZE-BALLZ` is listed above a 5-star review with no text.  Is there a better, more efficient to write this?

Comment: I don't know if `mongodb` supports complex ordering like that ([a quick google suggests "no"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38369862/1954610), but I could have missed something). However, for performance you could instead add a **new** database field called `review_text_length` or `review_text_present`? This would allow you to simply order by that field's size/presence.

Comment: @TomLord: good idea, thanks!